# How to display Get and Post action result in same view in mvc5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi  i have one view called Sales Visit. In that view i have two textboxes **FromDate** and **Todate**. If i select the FromDate and Todate and click the ok button it pass the dates to post action of SalesVisit in Controller.

In the controller it calculated one values depends upon the dates criteria. Now i want to show that result which i calculated in the post action in controller in same view. Eg which is shown in the below image.

[image: Example View]

In the above image i have two textboxes if i select the from date and two date and click the ok button means it pass the dates to controller and in controller it calculate some value and again it have to pass the result to same view.
Eg in the above image i draw two boxes with values (red colour boxes).How I bring that result.

**My Model(Dashboard View Model)**

```
public class DashboardViewmodel
  {
   public List<CustomerTypeCountModel> CustomerTypesCountModels { get; set;}
    public List<View_VisitorsForm> Visits { get; set; }
    public CustomerTypeViewModel CustomerTypeViewModels { get; set; }
    public int sizingcount { get; set; }
    public int Processingcount { get; set; }
}
```

**My Controller Code**

```
     public ActionResult SalesVisit()
      {
        return View();
      }
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult GetDatesFromSalesVisit(DashboardViewmodel dvm)
    {

        var fromdate = Convert.ToDateTime(dvm.CustomerTypeViewModels.FromDate);
        var todate = Convert.ToDateTime(dvm.CustomerTypeViewModels.ToDate);

        var userID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString();
        var objEmpDepUTID = db.UserRightsSettings.Where(u => u.UserID.ToString() == userID).Select(e => new
        {
            objemployeeID = e.EmployeeID,
            objdepartmentID = e.DepartmentID,
            objusertypeID = e.UserTypeID
        }).FirstOrDefault();

        var EmployeeID = objEmpDepUTID.objemployeeID;
        var DepartmentID = objEmpDepUTID.objdepartmentID;
        var UserTypeID = objEmpDepUTID.objusertypeID;
        var processingdeptid = (from d in db.Departments where d.DisplayName == "Processing" select d.DepartmentID).FirstOrDefault();
        var sizingdeptid = (from d in db.Departments where d.DisplayName == "Sizing" select d.DepartmentID).FirstOrDefault();

        List<View_VisitorsForm> objsizingcount = new List<View_VisitorsForm>();
        List<View_VisitorsForm> objprocessingcount = new List<View_VisitorsForm>();

        if (DepartmentID == new Guid("47D2C992-1CB6-44AA-91CA-6AA3C338447E") &&
            (UserTypeID == new Guid("106D02CC-7DC2-42BF-AC6F-D683ADDC1824") ||
            (UserTypeID == new Guid("B3728982-0016-4562-BF73-E9B8B99BD501"))))
        {
           var sizingview_visitorsforms = db.View_VisitorsForm.Where(x => x.EmpDepID == processingdeptid && x.VisitingDate >= fromdate 
                && x.VisitingDate <= todate).ToList();
           var processingview_visitorsform = db.View_VisitorsForm.Where(x => x.EmpDepID == sizingdeptid && x.VisitingDate >= fromdate 
                && x.VisitingDate <= todate).ToList();

            objsizingcount = sizingview_visitorsforms;
            objprocessingcount = processingview_visitorsform;
         }
        DashboardViewmodel obj = new DashboardViewmodel();
        obj.sizingcount = objsizingcount.Count();
        obj.Processingcount = objprocessingcount.Count();
        return View("SalesVisit", obj);
    }
```

**My view Code**

```
  @model  CostToWafe.Areas.Sales.Models.DashboardViewmodel
  @using  CostToWafe.Areas.Sales.Models
  @{
    ViewBag.Title = "SalesVisit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }

   @using (Html.BeginForm("GetDatesFromSalesVisit","AdminDashboard"))
  {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
   <body>
   <div class="col-sm-3">
   <div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("From Date")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerTypeViewModels.FromDate, new { @class = "form-control", id = "FromDate" })
    </div>
    </div>

   <div class="col-sm-3">
   <div class="form-group">
   @Html.Label("To Date")
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerTypeViewModels.ToDate, new { @class = "form-control", id = "ToDate" })
   </div>
   </div>
```

I tried Partial view but it showing **object reference not set to an instance of an object** error. I tried my level best to explain my issue.Any one understand my issue and help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to stay on the same page, then use ajax to post the values and return a`PartialViewResult` or `JsonResult` and update the DOM with the returned result.

Comment: @StephenMuecke any example?

Comment: There are thousands of examples on the web :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i am asking some example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetDatesFromSalesVisit", "AdminDashboard", new AjaxOptions {
    UpdateTargetId = "visitDiv" 
}
```

Add this to your view to direct the result to a partial view.

```
@Html.Partial("_sales")
```

Then return PartialViewResult from controller.

```
return PartialView("_sales", obj);
```

Create the partial view _sales and put a div inside it with the model data.

```
<div id="visitDiv">
  @model.sizingcount
</div>
```

Comment: Ok i have a try Janne

Comment: Janne I have one doubt i declare this code in top of the view          @using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetDatesFromSalesVisit", "AdminDashboard", new AjaxOptions {
    UpdateTargetId = "visitDiv" 
}  My doubt is where i have to write that body textbox field code Inside of this Ajax.Beginform or ouside ??

Comment: Janne I tried as per you said but i am getting one html error but in view it wont show any error ..The error is mention in the below image.                                 https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmpSf.jpg                                                           https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKX65.jpg           Kindly have a check and let me know  what mistake i did

Comment: You need to insert "{" and "}" before and after the <body> tags. All html after Beginform method must be inside brackets.

Comment: Yes i did that but i am getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error while i try to load a page

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T18LP.jpg  i used tha brackets after that i am getting this error

Comment: Check that the model has a value. Put this before using your model in the partial view: @if (Model != null).

Comment: Now no error the value is also calculated correctly but in view page it not showing any out put

Comment: Check your controller code. It should have this definition: public PartialViewResult GetDatesFromSalesVisit and this result: return PartialView("_sales", obj). It works if your model has data.

Comment: Actually I didnt use public PartialViewResult GetDatesFromSalesVisit  but i Used return PartialView("_sales", obj). ok i change action result to partialviewresult and have a check

Comment: Janne I did as per u said. this is my view code https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rqvJ.jpg                                                                        this is my partial view code                                                                                          https://i.stack.imgur.com/224jl.jpg                                                                              this is my result  .https://i.stack.imgur.com/224jl.jpg . it empty. All are working fine. if i select date it come to controller counting value and go to partial view there also values there but in view  not vsible

Comment: Janne I did as per u said. this is my view code i.stack.imgur.com/7rqvJ.jpg this is my partial view code i.stack.imgur.com/224jl.jpg this is my result https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rqvJ.jpg. it empty. All are working fine. if i select date it come to controller counting value and go to partial view there also values there but in view not vsible

Comment: Janne I did as per u said. this is my view code https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rqvJ.jpg  this is my partial view code https://i.stack.imgur.com/224jl.jpg this is my result https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWfG4.jpg. it empty. All are working fine. if i select date it come to controller counting value and go to partial view there also values there but in view not vsible

Comment: Try removing the form tags. BeginForm method already adds form tags to your page and these additional tags only make your controls render on different forms.